# Method undefined in Angular JS service unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am writing unit tests for my existing AngularJS app.  There are just four methods in this service.  I was able to getFollowUpList to work, but refresh() is not working and it is a very simple method.

The refresh method should simply set deferredGetFollowUpList = null and return true in my test.

There error I'm getting is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`, so my refresh method is undefined.  Why is this the case?  Thanks

**Service**

```
(function () {
   "use strict";

   angular
      .module("all.patient.details")
      .factory("followUpListService", ["$rootScope", "$http", "userContext", "$q", "$uibModal", "htmlBaseUrl", FollowUpListService]);

   function FollowUpListService($rootScope, $http, userContext, $q, $uibModal, htmlBaseUrl) {
      var deferredGetFollowUpList = null;

      return {
         getFollowUpList: getFollowUpList,
         displayModal: displayModal,
         refresh: refresh,
         save: save
      }

      function refresh() {
         deferredGetFollowUpList = null;
      }
   }
})();
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe("followUpListService", function () {

    beforeEach(module("all.patient.details"));
    var followUpListService = {};
    var $httpBackend;
    var htmlBaseUrlMock;
    var returnedFollowUpListData;
    var deferredGetFollowUpList;
    var $rootScope;
    var $q;
    var $uibModal;

    beforeEach(function () {

        htmlBaseUrlMock = { format: function () { } };     

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value("htmlBaseUrl", htmlBaseUrlMock);
        });

        inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _$q_, _$uibModal_, _followUpListService_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $q = _$q_;
            $uibModal = _$uibModal_;
            followUpListService = _followUpListService_;          
        });

    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it("calls refresh()", function () {

        followUpListService.refresh()
        .then(function (data) {
            deferredGetFollowUpList = data;
        });

        expect(deferredGetFollowUpList).toBe(null);
    });
```

Comment: Refresh is function that returns `undefined`. Undefined doesn't have property than - so, this is the source of error. You need to return promise from `refresh()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As `deferredGetFollowUpList` is service level variable, Can you write your test as -

```
followUpListService.deferredGetFollowUpList = data; //Any Mock Data
followUpListService.refresh();
expect(followUpListService.deferredGetFollowUpList).toBe(null);
```